# What's an appropriate design for creating different objects/invoking different methods depending on use case?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm not too sure what this use-case is called but let me explain: I am developing a service that uploads data. My service handles different types of uploads and each upload type is unique e.g. content of `UPLOAD_A` != content of `UPLOAD_B`.

The data comes to me a json file. From the json file, I know what type of upload it is. I need to parse this json into an appropriate `UploadDataX` object. For example, if I get a json data file for `UPLOAD_A`, I need to serialise this into an `UploadDataA` object.

Once I have my `UploadDataX` object, I will need to upload the data. I do this by using an external client object: `UploadClient()`. However, I need to invoke specific upload methods depending on the data type. For example, for an `UPLOAD_A` type, I need to invoke `UploadClient().uploadDataA(UploadDataA)` and for an `UPLOAD_B` type, I need to invoke `UploadClient().uploadDataB(uploadDataB)`.

The problem is that I do not own any of these `UploadDataX` and the client object. Unfortunately, the `UploadDataX` do not come under a super-class. I'm wondering what is an effective design pattern for dealing with this use-case?

I can think of a brute force solution, using simple switch-case statements:

```
// BRUTE FORCE SOLUTION
public void upload(UploadType uploadType, String jsonString) {
   switch (uploadType) {
      case UPLOAD_A: {
         UploadDataA uploadDataA = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UploadDataA.class);
         UploadClient().uploadDataA(uploadDataA);
         break;
      }
      case UPLOAD_B: {
         UploadDataB uploadDataB = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UploadDataB.class);
         UploadClient().uploadDataB(uploadDataB);
         break;
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

as you can see, this seems repetitive and I can't help but feel there is a better design approach. I was thinking about a Factory pattern but I want to see what everyone else thinks.

Comment: What you need is a simple polymorphism :) If you have an `UploadType`, make it an interface with a single method `upload(json)`. Then you can have different implementations: `UplaodA implements UploadType` etc and each `upload()` method will have the corresponding impl from your switch arm above :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public enum UploadType implements BiConsumer<UploadClient, String> {
    UPLOAD_A(UploadDataA.class, (ulc, obj) -> ulc.uploadDataA((UploadDataA) obj)),
    UPLOAD_B(UploadDataA.class, (ulc, obj) -> ulc.uploadDataB((UploadDataB) obj))
    // etc
    ;

    private Class<?> clazz;
    private BiConsumer<UploadClient, Object> uploader;

    UploadType(Class<?> clazz, BiConsumer<UploadClient, Object> uploader) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.uploader = uploader;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(UploadClient uploadClient, String jsonString) {
        Object obj = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, clazz);
        uploader.accept(uploadClient, obj);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public void upload(UploadType uploadType, String jsonString) {
    uploadType.accept(UploadClient(), jsonString);
}
```

Voila!

This maximizes code reuse, and minimizes the effort to add more upload types.

---

To keep things separated, use maps to look up the classes and lambdas:

```
private Map<UploadType, Class<?>> uploadClasees = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(UploadType.UPLOAD_A, UploadDataA.class);
    put(UploadType.UPLOAD_B, UploadDataB.class);
}};

private Map<UploadType, BiConsumer<UploadClient, Object>> uploaders = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(UploadType.UPLOAD_A, (ulc, obj) -> ulc.uploadDataA((UploadDataA) obj));
    put(UploadType.UPLOAD_B, (ulc, obj) -> ulc.uploadDataB((UploadDataB) obj));
}};

public void upload(UploadType uploadType, String jsonString) {
    BiConsumer<UploadClient, Object> uploader = uploaders.get(uploadType);
    Class<?> clazz = uploadClasees.get(uploadType);
    Object obj = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, clazz);
    uploader.accept(new UploadClient(), obj);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution as the invocation-part is really straight forward. What concerns me a bit is kinda minor. My UploadType and UploadClient live in separate packages (essentially different repos) because I wanted to follow good separation of responsibilities. If I go with this approach, then my UploadType package will have to depend on my clients package, which is not ideal as the inverse dependency already exists. The circular dependency is a problem; I guess I have to move the client to the other package then

Comment: I know what you mean and that’s a fair criticism. You can keep them separate by using a map of UploadType to the lambdas, and the map can be just in your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the map suggestion, I don't follow

Comment: @Kiwibreeder See edited answer for the decoupled version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the upload type in advance, as in your example, then you only need a simple polymorphism:

```java
interface UploadType{
   void upload(String json) throws SomeException;
}

class UploadTypeA implements UploadType{
    void upload(String json) throws SomeException{
        //code from your example
        UploadDataA uploadDataA = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UploadDataA.class);
        UploadClient().uploadDataA(uploadDataA);
    }
}

class UploadTypeB implements UploadType{
    void upload(String json) throws SomeException{
        //code from your example
        UploadDataB uploadDataB = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UploadDataB.class);
        UploadClient().uploadDataB(uploadDataB);
    }
}
```

Then the upload method in your example will look like:

```java
public void upload(UploadType uploadType, String jsonString) {
    uploadType.upload(jsonString);
}
```

So you can just remove/inline it if it does not have any other code inside

Comment: Question: this seems to require moving my UploadType from an Enum to an interface. Besides that, I'm struggling to understand how this is beneficial as I'm just moving all of the serialisation and specific invocation into another class

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces too and also each variant can haave different implementation (with or without an interface). Regarding the second part of your question, see [replace conditional with polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)